# what does two different sets of brackets mean around a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning about sets and I've come across this question.

{x} ∈ {{x}}

I have to answer whether this statement is true or not. I put down true but I'm not 100% sure. If anyone can clear up what the two sets of brackets mean and if I was correct that would be great. Thanks

Comment: True. {{$x$}} = {$x$} . The extra pair of brackets makes no sense in this case

Comment: I believe it means that the element x belongs to the set of elements x. {x} being the element x and {{x}} being the set of elements x.

Comment: @slhulk you're mistaken: $\{\{x\}\} \ne \{x\}$

Comment: You should also ask... is $x\in\{\{x\}\}$?

Comment: x∈{{x}} isn't that also true?

Comment: No: $\{x\}\in \{\{x\}\}$ but $x\notin\{\{x\}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

See it this way: $x$ is an object. Then $\{x\}$ is a set consisting of this single object $x$. Such a set is called a *singleton*. Finally $X:=\bigl\{\{x\}\bigr\}$ is a set of sets, containing the single set $\{x\}$. As a set $X$ is a singleton as well. The question now is whether this $X$ contains the set $\{x\}$ as an element; and this is obviously **true**.

Answer (score 2):

For *any* expression $A$, "$\{A\}$" means "the set whose only element is $A$".  In particular, when $A=\{x\}$, $\{\{x\}\}$ means the set whose only element is $\{x\}$.  That is, the double brackets have no special meaning; they are just two pairs of single brackets which happen to be nested.

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets $\{\}$denotes a set.
So you have two sets, one $\{x\}$ and another $\{\{x\}\}$, lets denote the first set as $A=\{x\}$ , then the second set is $\{A\}$ and your statement is whether $A\in\{A\}$ or not, which is of course true.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this made it a lot clearer.